# How I can develop a screen-capture tool in Python

Tags: python, screen-capture

I'm learning Python now and I want to develop a screen capture tool in Python.How I can do this work?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which online resources (other then SO!) have you consulted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on windows, use [ImageGrab module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm) along with [Imaging library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Something like:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
ImageGrab.grab().save("screenshot.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be create a higher level interface to ffmpeg. Unless you want to write the code to deal with X11 and record the screen, then it would be the best option.

If you test it on various platforms, then give useful error messages on things like incompatible sound systems, where to get certain video drivers, etc then this could be a pretty useful program.